# How to make a 360' panorama taking screenshots of a 3D enviroment

Tags: panorama, 360-panorama, 3d

I found very interesting to create a panoramic photos by stitching different pictures taken from a pre built 3D environment. For many reasons :

1) a lot of panoramic photos cannot be used because they are copyrighted

2) a lot of panoramic photos found on the net are not suitable for the needs

3) the panoramic photos found on the net are hard to modify

4) I haven't a camera and I'm not a photographer

5) on the net there are a lot of 3d environment to use to make a 360 panorama

6) to render a full 3d environment takes time and it needs powerful computers

So,on blenderswap I found the 3D model of a restaurant created with blender 3D. I captured 16 screenshots from different angles of the room and I tried to stitch them with PTgui and Hugin but at some point it asked to me to define the control points. I have clicked over the numbers indicated by the tool on the left and on the right side of the screen,but the final panorama created by the tool is never good. Maybe because I don't understand where to place markers or Maybe because I make wrong screenshots or maybe because I'm not using a good camera with the fish eye. I don't know. Please help me understand how to make this job.

This is the link of the 3d environment that I'm working with :

[3D restaurant](http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/73530)

here you can find the pictures that I have taken from the different angles of the room :

[3d room screenshots](https://postimg.org/gallery/1fqb588oe/2d4bc214/)

PTgui told me these error messages :

[image: error 1] 
[image: error 2]

and this is one of the final result :

[image: final panorama]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about 3D rendering of artificial scenes, not photography.

Comment: what's the right section to post this question ?

Comment: "*what's the right section to post this question ?*" Try [blender.se]

Comment: Is [this your question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36573/equirectangular-rendering-for-blender-internal)? :)

Answer (score 2):

To create a panoramic image, all the parts must be shot from the same place, so they can be stitched together. Your snapshots are from different places, and because of that they can't be used to make a panorama.
Next time try just rotating the view without moving or zooming, and make sure all images overlap at least 20%.

On the other hand, panoramic pictures are done by stitching pictures just because of physical limitations: not having a wide enough lens, or getting more resolution, but on a 3d render it doesn't really make much sense, as you can just render the 360 view directly. It can be useful as a learning exercise, though.